# How do I set color to Rectangle in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I set color to Rectangle for example in matplotlib? I tried using argument color, but had no success.

I have following code:

```
fig=pylab.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

pylab.xlim([-400, 400])    
pylab.ylim([-400, 400])
patches = []
polygon = Rectangle((-400, -400), 10, 10, color='y')
patches.append(polygon)

p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet)
ax.add_collection(p)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(20))    
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(20))    

pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I couldn't get your code to work, but hopefully this will help:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rect1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-200,-100), 400, 200, color='yellow')
rect2 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0,150), 300, 20, color='red')
rect3 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-300,-50), 40, 200, color='#0099FF')
circle1 = matplotlib.patches.Circle((-200,-250), radius=90, color='#EB70AA')
ax.add_patch(rect1)
ax.add_patch(rect2)
ax.add_patch(rect3)
ax.add_patch(circle1)
plt.xlim([-400, 400])
plt.ylim([-400, 400])
plt.show()
```

produces:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Turns out, you need to do `ax.add_artist(Rectangle)` to have the color specifications work; when using `patches.append(Rectangle)`, the rectangle is shown in blue (on my PC, at least) ignoring any color specification.

Btw, note that [artists — Matplotlib 1.2.1 documentation: class matplotlib.patches.Rectangle](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) states that there is

- `edgecolor` - for stroke color
- `facecolor` - for fill color

... and then there is `color` - which basically sets both stroke and fill color at the same time.

Here is the modified OP code, which I've tested on Linux (Ubuntu 11.04), python 2.7, matplotlib 0.99.3:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as collections
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

import matplotlib
print matplotlib.__version__ # 0.99.3

fig=plt.figure() #pylab.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_xlim([-400, -380]) #pylab.xlim([-400, 400])
ax.set_ylim([-400, -380]) #pylab.ylim([-400, 400])
patches = []
polygon = plt.Rectangle((-400, -400), 10, 10, color='yellow') #Rectangle((-400, -400), 10, 10, color='y')
patches.append(polygon)

pol2 = plt.Rectangle((-390, -390), 10, 10, facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='violet', linewidth=2.0)
ax.add_artist(pol2)


p = collections.PatchCollection(patches) #, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet)
ax.add_collection(p)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(20)) # (MultipleLocator(20)) 
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(20)) # (MultipleLocator(20)) 

plt.show() #pylab.show()
```

this is the output:

[image: matplotlib.png]

Answer (score 4):

To avoid calling `.add_patch()` multiple times (often the purpose of using PatchCollection in the first place), you can pass a `ListedColormap` to the `PatchCollection` via `cmap=`.

This looks as follows (modified from [fraxel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10551413/5516420)):

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
patches_list = []
color_list = []
patches_list.append(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-200,-100), 400, 200))
color_list.append('yellow')
patches_list.append(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0,150), 300, 20))
color_list.append('red')
patches_list.append(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-300,-50), 40, 200))
color_list.append('#0099FF')
patches_list.append(matplotlib.patches.Circle((-200,-250), radius=90))
color_list.append('#EB70AA')

our_cmap = ListedColormap(color_list)
patches_collection = PatchCollection(patches_list, cmap=our_cmap)
patches_collection.set_array(np.arange(len(patches_list)))
ax.add_collection(patches_collection)

plt.xlim([-400, 400])
plt.ylim([-400, 400])
plt.show()
```

Result:
[cmap_approach_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apRJe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. Passing in `color=` to `Rectangle()` will only work if you specify `match_original=True` when you create your `PatchCollection()`. See [PatchCollection()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection) for the details.

A simplified version of @Didillysquat's example is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
patches_list = []
color_list = []
patches_list.append(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-200,-100), 400, 200, color='yellow'))
patches_list.append(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0,150), 300, 20, color='red'))
patches_list.append(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-300,-50), 40, 200, color='#0099FF'))
patches_list.append(matplotlib.patches.Circle((-200,-250), radius=90, color='#EB70AA'))

# Make sure you use match_original=True
patches_collection = PatchCollection(patches_list, match_original=True)
ax.add_collection(patches_collection)

plt.xlim([-400, 400])
plt.ylim([-400, 400])
plt.show()
```