# Polygon to binary mask

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I've made a polygon using shapely.geometry, then put it into a geopandas dataframe.
I've made an array with the same size as the polygon zone

How can I turn this polygon into a binary mask, so I can shape my array as a polygon too?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think I saw in some question: draw polygon with `matplotlib` and get result as image which is a array.

Comment: Is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64153744/overwrite-points-from-pcolormesh-if-they-arent-contained-in-a-polygon  what you want to do?

Comment: @swatchai exactly. But I managed to do it using polygon.contains(). I ll post my method next week

Comment: Hi, has the method been posted? I was unable to find it and have been looking to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Not the most efficient method but it worked.

First I make a mask on the grid, with False on data that is not in the polygon (using contains method).
Second I multiply the array by that mask, then take 0 as NaNs.

Here is an example of my code :

```
# g is anarray with flatten x y coordinates
g = np.stack([
        xi.flatten(),
        yi.flatten(),]) 

# Function to check if in polygon, return bool
def func1d(row, args):
    return args.contains(Point(row[1], row[0]))

# Take mask array and apply along axis, poly is the polygon that we want to use
mask = np.apply_along_axis(func1d, 1, g, args=poly)
g[:,2] = g[:,2]*mask
g[g==0]=[np.NaN] # get 0 be nans (should be a better way to do this but was ok here)
output = g[~np.isnan(g).any(axis=1)] # filter to only save the polygon data
```